# Sort specific element without reordering others

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm trying to write a one-liner to sort an array where I just push all zeroes to the end of the array. This is my code:

```js
const arr = [ 9, 0, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9 ];

arr.sort((a,b) => (a === 0 && b !== 0) ? 1 : (b === 0 && a !== 0) ? -1 : 0);

console.log(`[${arr.join(', ')}]`);
// [9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

However, this code also seems to order other elements somehow, for the array

I expect
`[9,9,1,2,1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`
But I got
`[9,9,9,9,1,2,1,1,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`
Any clues?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, I get your expected output. What environment (e.g. browser) are you using, does it have an old javascript engine that does not yet implement a stable sort?

Answer (score 2):

I am getting your expected result.
But you can also use filter since it returns a new array. Concat the first one (without zeroes) to the second one (only zeroes).

```js
let arr = [ 9, 0, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9 ];
arr = arr.filter(a => a !== 0).concat(arr.filter(a => a === 0));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much a one liner... sort of. Uses a temp array to store the zeros

```js
let n = [9, 0, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]

let c = [], newn = n.filter(e => (e === 0 && c.push(e)) ? false : true).concat(c)
console.log(newn)
```